How would you implement "long" Keyboard shortcut sequences in Avalonia?
Some applications, like Visual Studio, support long keyboard shortcut sequences. For instance, the command Toggle bookmark is bound to the sequence Ctrl+K Ctrl+K. When writing an Avalonia application, how would you approach implementing this keyboard sequence?
Since KeyGesture only supports a single (modifier + Key) combination, it seems I'd have to build an intermediate handler that reacts to the initial Ctrl+K (maybe displaying a status bar message like "Waiting for next key press..."). The next Ctrl+K would then have to be handled by the intermediate handler, which would dispatch to an actal ToggleBookmark command -- or handle the ESC key to get out of the modal state introduced by this mechanism.
The kicker is that once the handler has received Ctrl+K, I have to rewire the window so that all keyboard events are routed to intermediate handler, and after the second event has been handled, the rewiring has to be restored to its original state. It's unclear how I'd do this, and whether it is the right approach.
So, is this the Right Way(TM), or is there a more appropriate approach?
